# My flash video object works fine in Mozilla browsers but not in IE (I'm using IE7)

Tags: flash, internet-explorer

A simple flash video doesn't appear in IE. I've looked at answers to the same problem by NineBerry, however, I've tried those suggestions without luck.

You can see the page at http://sunscreenwear.com/children/media/mulholland_intro_slideshow.html.

The media folder contains the following files:
mulholland_intro_slideshow.flv,
mulholland_intro_slideshow.html.
mulholland_intro_slideshow.swf,
and ClearOverPlaySeekMute.swf.

I didn't include the file mulholland_intro_slideshow.fla as I doesn't seem necessary.

I'm also aware that when encoding with Flash the object can only be made to played locally or via the network. I encoded locally for testing but it also plays across the network. Is that even relevant? I don't know.

I'd appreciate all the help I can get.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: What Flash versions do you have installed in Mozilla, and IE, respectively?

Answer (score 1):

Your `<title>` tag isn't closed properly. IE will pick up on this, Firefox will let it slide.
Change `/title>` to `</title>` and it should then work properly in IE.

Comment: That's the issue.  Just when you think Flash is always the culprit.

Comment: Flash may be sometimes but IE is always a culprit. BTW: What gave it away, the document title was appearing as /title> in the IE application title bar.